# Ionic v3: How to copy ion-grid table to excel

Tags: ionic3

I’m trying to copy a girded data to excel as a table.

this is my code

```
<ion-grid>
   <ion-row *ngFor="let row of ['', '', '', '', '', '']; let i=index;">
      <ion-col col-3 *ngFor="let col of ['', '', '', '']; let j=index;" style="border:1px solid black;">
        TEST {{i}}.{{j}}
      </ion-col>
   </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
```

When I paste the table into excel, it print as a one line instated of table.

Comment: At the end of each row, you need to indent it to go to new line, in row ngfor, its being compilied normally with comma (','), but the output is without comma, the outpit should be in this form, row1,row2, etc... in order to achieve it , you need to concatinate the string, so it will be like this, copyMethod() { let stringData =""; for let i=0; i<rowsCount;i++) { if (i< rowsCount-1) { stringData += column[0] + " " + column[2] + etc ... +",";} else { stringData += same as the above but with adding comma at end} and by this way it will be as csv data that can work on excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is no other than this way

```
<table width="100%">
  <tr *ngFor="let row of ['', '', '', '', '', '']; let i=index;">
    <td text-center *ngFor="let col of ['', '', '', '']; let j=index;" style="border:1px solid black;">
      TEST {{i}}.{{j}}
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```